# How to override method via keyboard shortcut in Android Studio

Tags: android, methods, overriding, keyboard-shortcuts

I can finally ask a question to get my points up.

In android studio, I want to be able to override the method, however I do not know the keyboard shortcut.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can not remember all shortcuts :)
Android Studio(actually Intellij)
has a solution

**quick command search : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>**

[image: screenShot of SearchBox]

if you have more memory here it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Type `constructor` to override all of them quickly :D

Comment: There are answers which just answer the question asked. And there are answers which go one step ahead. You nailed it!

Comment: @RBT I gave one answer for all shortcut finders on intellij based IDEs. if they post questions for for each and every shortcut it's inefficient :). so why shouldn't upvote. I save network traffic .

Comment: yep. Very true. Keep sharing and keep posting!

Comment: Teach a man to fish! I had no idea, thanks! :)

Answer (score 47):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

For more shortcut look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171117101309/http://kevinpratama.com/2013/05/17/android-studio-keyboard-shortcut/) (archive.org mirror)

Comment: same for Mac OS

Comment: great time saver, would press again. Also i updated the link to archive.org ref as the site was down

Comment: worthy to mention to find specific method use f button. as ctrl+f does nothing here.

Answer (score 13):

Windows and Linux
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Mac
<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

---

Complete IntelliJ shortcuts

[Windows and Linux](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

[MacOSX](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf)

Comment: I have tried editing the current accepted answer to make it more complete, but it was refused. So I added my own answer since I'm using mac.

Comment: bonus for the mac

Comment: What a great tool which allows me to reduce at least half a day trying to search a lot!

Comment: On my MacBook Pro keyboard the key is actually labeled "control", not "^".

Answer (score 1):

ctrl + o -> windows shows overriden method in Android Studio